# Simple Linq Join

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have 3 related tables in my employee.dbml

```
Emp        dept        Zone 
empId      deptID      ZoneID 
empName    deptName    ZoneType
empage                 deptID 
empzone
deptID
```

Now how do I get ZoneType by passing empid in a query in linQ

Please help

Comment: Perhaps I just don't fully understand the columns in your tables, but some of the foreign keys in your tables look a little fishy to me...

Answer (score 3):

Based on your description, you shouldn't need to join in the Dept table.

Also, this will return an IEnumerable, so if you want a single value, you will need to appropriately handle the case where this returns no results, or multiple results.

```
int empid = GetEmpId();

var query =
   from e in db.Emp
   join z in db.Zone on e.deptId equals z.deptId
   where e.empid == empid
   select z.ZoneType;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it if I am understanding your tables correctly:

```
var result = (
    from e in dbContext.Emp
    join zone_join in dbContext.Zone
        on e.deptID equals zone_join.ZoneID
    where e.empId == YourEmpID
    select zone_join.ZoneType).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me the role that `Dept` is playing here; as described it appears that `Emp`s can be joined to `Zone`s without using `Dept` as an intermediary.

```
// these could be Tables in a DataContext
IEnumerable<Emp> emps;
IEnumerable<Zone> zones

var result = (from e in emps
              join z in zones on e.deptId equals z.DeptId
              where e.empId == employeeID
              select z.ZoneType).Single();
```

Perhaps you meant for `Dept` to have a column named `ZoneID`? Then you would say:

```
// these could be Tables in a DataContext
IEnumerable<Emp> emps;
IEnumerable<Dept> depts;
IEnumerable<Zone> zones;

var result = (from e in emps
              join d in depts on e.deptId equals d.deptId
              join z in zones on d.ZoneID equals z.ZoneID
              where e.empId == employeeId
              select z.ZoneType).Single();
```

Because of the ambiguity in your question I can not give you a definitive answer but the above should be enough to point you in the right direction. If not, please feel free to post a comment requesting clarification.